# What is the meaning of $\Sigma_n, \Pi_n, \Delta_n$ without superscript symbols?

Tags: notation

Sometimes I see the $\Sigma_n, \Pi_n, \Delta_n$ notation without superscript symbols (for example, in [this answer on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/141858); another example is [hypermachines ($\Sigma_n$-machines)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220315602_Hypermachines)). But when I read articles on Wikipedia ([Descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory), [Arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy), [Hyperarithmetical theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory), [Analytical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/), [Projective hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_hierarchy), [Borel hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy)), I only see the notation with superscript symbols, and I cannot find what is implied by $\Sigma_n, \Pi_n, \Delta_n$. Why is the superscript symbol omitted?

Comment: It may depend on the context, but probably it's the sum, &c, from $n=0$ (or $1$, depending on the convention) to $\infty$.

Comment: @Bernard: If you mean [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation), then no, the $\Sigma$ symbol in my question is not related to this. I added another example.

Answer (score 2):

This notation implies a formula in the [Lévy hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy).

Comment: It's also used interchangeably with $\Sigma^0_n$ etc. in many circumstances - e.g. in the notation "I$\Sigma_n$" for the fragment of PA with induction restricted to $\Sigma_n$, or $\Sigma^0_n$, sentences. Really it's a "flexible" notation, which can be applied to whatever complexity hierarchy we're in.